# Get current date in js using countdown

Tags: javascript

Searching for 30mins to get the current date is js.
Here is the part of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            JBCountDown({
                secondsColor : "#ffdc50",
                secondsGlow  : "none",

                minutesColor : "#9cdb7d",
                minutesGlow  : "none",

                hoursColor   : "#378cff",
                hoursGlow    : "none",

                daysColor    : "#ff6565",
                daysGlow     : "none",

                startDate   : "1398092400",
                endDate     : "1398524400",
                now         : "Date.now()"
            });
        });
```

Already tried several things without success.

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: `var date = new Date(); date.getTime()`? `Date.now()` does not exist which you could have seen by the errors it gives you.

Comment: Tried everything. But just found a solution. I used: <?php echo time(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You have put `Date.now()` in inverted commas so it would be treated as a String.
Also `Date.now()` only appears to exist in a Microsoft javascript library.

@putvande was correct.

if you change the now line as follows:

```
now: new Date().getTime()
```

but without inverted commas it should work.
However I also note that startDate and endDate are also in inverted commas, so will be strings, not longs. Also they look like Unix dates i.e. number of seconds from 1.1.1970, whereas new Date().getTime() will give no of milliseconds from 1.1.1970